# ¿Por qué me da este error?

Tags: python

> Crea una función que, dado un string, devuelva un diccionario con las
> letras presentes en ese string como claves y el número de veces que
> aparecen en el string como valores.

```
def cuenta_letras(string):

    contador_letras = {}

    for letra in string:
        if letra.isalpha():
            if letra.lower() in contador_letras:
                contador_letras[letra.lower()] += 1
            else:
                contador_letras[letra.lower()] = 1

    return contador_letras


string_ejemplo = "Hola, ¿cómo estás?"
resultado = cuenta_letras(string_ejemplo)
print(resultado)
```

Detalles del error

```
{'p': 1, 'y': 1, 't': 1, 'h': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1} != {'p': 1, 'y': 1, 't': 1, 'h': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, '3': 1, '_': 1, '1': 1, '0': 1}
- {'h': 1, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 1, 't': 1, 'y': 1}
+ {'0': 1, '1': 1, '3': 1, '_': 1, 'h': 1, 'n': 1, 'o': 1, 'p': 1, 't': 1, 'y': 1}
?  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 : Número de letras incorrecto.
```

Comment: puedes revisar la indentación?

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta el "error " tal vez **no** deberías excluir los caracteres numéricos y el "_" (`str.isalpha()`). Si te proporcionan una entrada ejemplo y su salida esperada, agregarla ayudaría a esclarecer el problema.

Comment: El mensaje de error no coincide con el código. No hay ninguna letra "y" , "p" o "n" en la frase "Hola, como estas?"

Comment: Esta es una [pregunta repetida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+contar+caracteres)